# How to rewrite a few numpy codes using Cython?

Tags: python, numpy, cython, numba

I just want to accelerate my numerical algorithm written in numpy. A critical part is to calculate the Log-likelihood function (the difference between two truncated normal CDF). My function is very slow (31.9 ms per loop) and I need to run it for 2000 time every iteration.

I have tried to use scipy's "norm.cdf" function instead of the "ecfc". But it is slower. I also tried "@jit" from the Numba package. But it was also slower than the original code.

I think maybe I need to use Cython. But I know next to nothing about C. I've tried to learn Cython from the [Cython for numpy users](http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/numpy_tutorial.html) webpage, but it was really to difficult for me.

Could anyone kindly help me to re-write the code in Cython? Or advise me how to write it faster?

```
import numpy as np 
from scipy.special import erfc
# The bloody function for calculating the difference between two truncated normal CDFs
def my_loglikelihood2(x,b,c,z):
    log_likelihood=np.zeros(np.shape(z)[0])
    log_likelihood[x==1]=np.log(0.5*erfc(-(c[1]-np.dot(z[x==1,:],b)) / np.sqrt(2.)) - 0.5*erfc(-(c[0]-np.dot(z[x==1],b)) / np.sqrt(2.)))
    log_likelihood[x==2]=np.log(0.5*erfc(-(c[2]-np.dot(z[x==2,:],b)) / np.sqrt(2.)) - 0.5*erfc(-(c[1]-np.dot(z[x==2],b)) / np.sqrt(2.)))
    log_likelihood[x==3]=np.log(0.5*erfc(-(c[3]-np.dot(z[x==3,:],b)) / np.sqrt(2.)) - 0.5*erfc(-(c[2]-np.dot(z[x==3],b)) / np.sqrt(2.)))
    return log_likelihood

# generate random values
x=np.random.randint(low=1, high=4, size=50000)
b=np.random.normal(0,1,70)
c=np.array([-999,-1,1,999],dtype='f')  
z=np.random.multivariate_normal(np.zeros(70), np.eye(70), 50000) 

%timeit my_loglikelihood2(x,b,c,z)

# 10 loops, best of 3: 31.9 ms per loop   :(
```

**Update 1 - base on the advice @jackvdp. It has been accerelated 4.5x times. But I am still looking for a even faster code:**

```
def up_cutoff(x,c):
    x[x==1]=c[1]
    x[x==2]=c[2]
    x[x==3]=c[3] 
    return x
def low_cutoff(x,c):
    x[x==1]=c[0]
    x[x==2]=c[1]
    x[x==3]=c[2] 
def my_loglikelihood2(x,b,low_c,up_c,z):
    up_c=up_cutoff(x,c)
    low_c=low_cutoff(x,c)
    return np.log(0.5*erfc(-(up_c-np.dot(z,b)) / np.sqrt(2.)) - 0.5*erfc(-(low_c-np.dot(z,b)) / np.sqrt(2.))) 

%timeit my_loglikelihood2(x,b,low_c,up_c,z)
100 loops, best of 3: 6.58 ms per loop
```

**Update 2 - base on the advice @DSM. Replace np.dot(z,b) by zdotb = z.dot(b) . Improved by 1.5ms**

```
def my_loglikelihood2(x,b,low_c,up_c,z):
    up_c=up_cutoff(x,c)
    low_c=low_cutoff(x,c)
    zdotb = z.dot(b)
    return np.log(0.5*erfc(-(up_c-zdotb) / np.sqrt(2.)) - 0.5*erfc(-(low_c-zdotb) / np.sqrt(2.))) 

%timeit my_loglikelihood2(x,b,low_c,up_c,z)
100 loops, best of 3: 5.02 ms per loop
```

Comment: I think you can make some progress on this without going to Cython. For example, why do you split up the log_likelihood computation into three steps? every one of them is essentially doing the same thing: you could combine them, remove a *lot* of mask indexing operations, and probably end up with faster code.

Comment: It looks like common subexpression elimination and advanced indexing (`c[x]` and `c[x-1]`) could speed this up a lot, pretty close to what Cython would get you.

Comment: Probably something like `zdotb = z.dot(b); return np.log(0.5*erfc(-(c[x]-zdotb) / np.sqrt(2.)) - 0.5*erfc(-(c[x-1]-zdotb) / np.sqrt(2.)))`. That might be wrong - I don't have the setup to test and debug NumPy code right now.

Comment: @jakevdp Thank you. I have updated the code using one line to compute the log_likelihood rather than 3 lines. And now it is 4.5x times faster. But I still want to speed up further..

Comment: As @user2357112 noted, you're not eliminating common subexpressions.  Even in your new code, you're computing `z.dot(b)` twice for some reason.

Comment: @DSM thank you. I have changed this. And it has been accelerate by 1.5ms. A big improvement for me. Thank you.

Comment: @user2357112 Thank you. I have tried but I don't how to define the c[x] and c[x-1]. I have used two functions to define them. Is it possible to use another to do that? Thank you!

Comment: @sc10mmj: Literally just `c[x]` and `c[x-1]`.

Comment: @user2357112 but c is 1x5 array.. I think I need to put a 1x50000 array here.. sorry. i was confused

Comment: @sc10mmj: Seriously, it's `c[x]` and `c[x-1]`. It's [NumPy advanced indexing](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing). (Also, c isn't 1x5. It has shape `(4,)`.)

Answer (score 1):

If your code was slow because of loops in Python, then porting it to Cython can see big improvements.  But your sample just calls existing numpy/scipy functions a half dozen times.

It's mostly calls to `np.log, erfc, np.dot, np.sqrt`.  I'm not sure about `erfc` but the others already use compiled code. Cython does not touch those.

We could examine `erfc`.

But the best bet is to call this code with larger arrays.

Comment: Thank you. But maybe erfc might not be a problem because it is just a function from Scipy.. I think all Scipy's functions or Numpy's functions are as fast as Cython. What do you think?

Comment: Yes, `erfc` and relatives are compiled, in https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/81c096001974f0b5efe29ec83b54f725cc681540/scipy/special/Faddeeva.cc